# What responsibilities does the Hurricane Harvey OPS team have, and what challenges?

Tags: nasa, weather

[Here is a tweet](https://twitter.com/Tungsten_Flight/status/902582635502870528) from NASA flight director Royce Renfrew's personal twitter account. I believe at least some of the Hurricane Harvey OPS team is on-site at [Johnson Space Center](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/home/index.html) but the work might be distributed. What kind of tasks and challenges does the Hurricane Harvey OPS team have? What's been going on there during the hurricane and its aftermath?

See also [NASA’s Johnson Space Center Closes for Hurricane Harvey](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-s-johnson-space-center-closes-for-hurricane-harvey).

[image]

Comment: They have the same tasks as MCC always has. I don't understand your question really since the problems of getting to work, making sure your family and property is safe, etc, seem pretty obvious. JSC is closed except to mission essential personnel till next Tuesday.

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/08/how-nasas-johnson-space-center-is-riding-out-the-hurricane/

Comment: @OrganicMarble You may not understand my question because you may know more about their responsibilities than I do, and so the answer may be obvious to you. I could vulgarize the question and ask "why didn't they just go home?" The staff that remained obviously have a critical function, and an answer here is an opportunity to point out what that would be, and to highlight the challenges and sacrifices that they are making. I've been a NASA fan for a half-century and watched them work miracles under a wide array of challenges. Here's yet another example of dedication and excellence.

Comment: @OrganicMarble your linked article mentions an important event, possibly you could expand on that?

Comment: Hmm. I didn't realize your question contained the sub-question What does ISS Mission Control Do.  I thought it was What does ISS MIssion Control Do Differently In a Hurricane.  To which the answer is, nothing, except maybe sleep in another room instead of going home.  What event are you referring to in the link?

Comment: @OrganicMarble ya it should be "What responsibilities does the Hurricane Harvey OPS team have, and what challenges?". I'll fix the title. The 2nd paragraph under the heading *No problem, Houston* seems to describe such a task, in addition to simply being constantly monitoring and staying prepared for a zillion different possible scenarios that haven't happen.

Comment: Thanks. In normal circumstances could probably write up an answer to What Does Mission Control Do.  But these are not normal circumstances in Houston this week.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it is easy (for most people) to forget that in addition to flying around the planets and taking pictures, NASA has also been in the business of keeping people alive 24/7 for the last 16 years and 301 days. (And of course so is Roscosmos).

Comment: I've created [What does the Mission control center do](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22904/what-does-the-iss-mission-control-center-do/22905) as a separate question, to make it easier to find. This means we can focus on just the unique parts of running the MCC during a hurricane here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Hurricane Harvey ops team' [is a subset of the flight operations team](http://www.floridatoday.com/story/tech/science/space/2017/08/28/mission-control-monitors-iss-closed-jsc/609211001/). They've kept working in the Mission Control Center while all other personnel has been sent home.

Challenge: being cooped up in the office for several days with a hurricane going on outside, possible utility interruptions due to storm damage.

> Despite the crisis unfolding flooding outside, ISS flight directors and more than 100 other “essential” personnel have ridden out the storm inside JSC’s iconic Mission Control Center to maintain watch over the ISS.
>
> Another flight director described the scene as surreal, with off-duty teams sleeping in a backup flight control room. Pictures showed cots lined up in front of a Flight Dynamics Officer’s console.
>
> Thanks in part to the team’s sacrifice, Harvey has caused no disruption to space station operations.

There's a backup flight control center:

> In one precautionary measure, downlinks of science research video has been rerouted to NASA’s Marshall Space Flight Center in Huntsville, Alabama, which can serve as a backup Mission Control Center in an emergency.

### Diversion:

(this was part of my initial answer, leaving it here because it's interesting)

For hurricanes etc., NASA assigns a rideout team to various locations. The rideout team watches the site for damage, tries to mitigate it and decides when it's safe for other personnel to enter the base.

Here's a story about how [NASA](https://blogs.nasa.gov/kennedy/2016/10/06/ksc-prepares-to-ride-out-matthew/) handled [hurricane Matthew](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2016/10/ksccape-hurcon-alert-matthew/) at [Cape Canaveral in 2016](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/hurricane-matthew-florida-kennedy-space-center-braces-for-storm/).

> Members of a 139-member “rideout” team will be stationed at various facilities across the space center to monitor critical systems “and report any significant events” to emergency operations personnel in the Complex 39 Launch Control Center where space shuttle launchings were once managed.
>
> “After the hurricane has passed, and winds have dropped below 50 knots, areas around KSC will be assessed and the damage assessment and recovery team will report for duty,” Diller said.

Comment: MCC has giant backup diesel generators.  There would be no utility interruptions unless the commercial power grid failed and also the diesels.

Comment: As I've [mentioned here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22837/#comment64977_22837) I'm not so familliar with operations there even when there isn't a weather emergency. This is a good summary of the challenges, could you also mention the tasks? I can see that it is felt to be critical to keep personnel there at all times, is more because of routine activities, or to be responsive to any unexpected or anomalous situations? Thanks!

Comment: Was there an orbital adjustment around Sunday August 27 "as the floodwaters rose" as mentioned in @OrganicMarble 's [link](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22837/what-responsibilities-does-the-hurricane-harvey-ops-team-have-and-what-challeng#comment64932_22837) to the [Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/08/how-nasas-johnson-space-center-is-riding-out-the-hurricane/) article? That would certainly count as a responsability, task or challenge. Then there is the recent return to Earth as well. Were some or all of these handled by the Harvey OPS team?